# Catel ViewModelToModel not linking

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, catel

I have a simple `ViewModel` which has two `Models`. So it looks like this:

```
public class ConnectionItemSelectorViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    ...

    #region AvailableConnectionsModel

    // Model Nr. 1
    [Model]
    public ConnectionList AvailableConnectionsModel
    {
        get { return GetValue<ConnectionList>(AvailableConnectionsModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AvailableConnectionsModelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData AvailableConnectionsModelProperty = RegisterProperty(nameof(AvailableConnectionsModel), typeof(ConnectionList), () => new ConnectionList());

    #endregion

    #region SelectedConnectionsModel

    // Model Nr. 2
    [Model]
    public ConnectionList SelectedConnectionsModel
    {
        get { return GetValue<ConnectionList>(SelectedConnectionsModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedConnectionsModelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData SelectedConnectionsModelProperty = RegisterProperty(nameof(SelectedConnectionsModel), typeof(ConnectionList), () => new ConnectionList());

    #endregion

    ...
}
```

`ConnectionList` extends `ModelBase` so I can use the `[Model]`-Attribute several times.

Now I want to expose the properties of the Model to the ViewModel:

```
public class ConnectionItemSelectorViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    ...
    // init Model properties

    #region AvailableConnections

    // Using a unique name for the property in the ViewModel
    // but linking to the "correct" property in the Model by its name
    [ViewModelToModel(nameof(AvailableConnectionsModel), nameof(ConnectionList.Connections))]
    public ObservableCollection<ConnectionItem> AvailableConnections
    {
        get { return GetValue<ObservableCollection<ConnectionItem>>(AvailableConnectionsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AvailableConnectionsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData AvailableConnectionsProperty = RegisterProperty(nameof(AvailableConnections), typeof(ObservableCollection<ConnectionItem>), () => null);

    #endregion

    // linking other properties to the models
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the linking doesn't work. So after initialization the property `AvailableConnections` (and the others also) are still `null`, though the Model itself is initialized correctly.

Am I missing something or isn't this possible at all?

thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `MappingType` on the ViewModelToModel attribute so that the model wins.

Comment: Thanks! Setting `Mode = ViewModelToModelMode.Explicit` works!